# I need to keep blacks beans and rice warm.

Tags: crockpot, pot

In about an hour I need to leave with a pot of black beans and rice. I don't have a crock pot, but I do have a cast iron pot with lid. To keep it all warm can I put it in an iron pot, and put it in the oven at 375F. Am I going to burn it if I leave it there for an hour? Should I lower the temperature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would place cooked beans and rice in a warmed pot (cast iron is good) and then place it in your oven set at its lowest temperature...Maybe 175F, and certainly below 200F.  At 375F your rice and beans will continue to cook.

Comment: And consider wrapping the pan in a towel or two after removing it from the oven.

Answer (score 2):

I leave leftovers warm for a couple of hours (when serving) as warm either at 200 F in the oven, or on the lowest setting on the stove (if it is something with soup or liquid, put baked/drier dishes in the oven.)